# Fill controll type Menu using ASP.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

is there any way to fill a controll type System.Web.UI.WebControls.Menu with data from database if i use ASP.Net MVC?

If yes how can i do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fill?  Probably.

Use effectively?  Probably not.

WebForm controls are built around the page lifecycle and viewstate.  MVC has neither of those.

Comment: is there any other way to create a menu thats quite similar to the asp controll?

Comment: Yes.  You're a developer, code away.  The jQuery library is pretty good for any javascript work.

Answer (score 0):

You could accomplish something similar by using a Partial View for your menu and create a ViewModel to populate it - just populate the ViewModel with your data from the DB. But otherwise Jfar is correct.

I'll get some links if I can - currently on my phone. Hope this helps some.